# Modbus Php read int16

Tags: php, modbus, plc

I've tried to access PLC Data int16 sent over ModbusTcp, but i'm receiving only 2x int8 (as two registers instead of one). Does anyone know how to change readable registers from 2x int8 into one int16?
Thanks in advance.

```
https://github.com/krakorj/phpmodbus/blob/cebe783e922232100b9f1b74f33613cdbd4bc809/Phpmodbus/ModbusMaster.php
```

Comment: Minimum, complete, verifiable, example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Convert the received Modbus data (array of bytes) to the PHP data type with the [PhpType](https://github.com/krakorj/phpmodbus/blob/cebe783e922232100b9f1b74f33613cdbd4bc809/Phpmodbus/PhpType.php) class.

```
$array = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, 1, 1);
$val_signedInt = PhpType::bytes2signedInt($array);
```